# How to use elastic search template id(stored in ES cluster) in spring boot get result

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I have an elastic search template stored in my ES we want to use this template-id in spring boot rest high client elastic search by passing the required parameter

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:9200/_scripts/my_template_id \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{
        "script": {
            "lang": "mustache",
            "source": {
              "query": {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "match": {
                        "studentName": {
                          "query": "{{query_string}}",
                          "operator": "or",
                          "fuzziness": 0,
                          "boost": 9
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "match": {
                        "studentId": {
                          "query": "{{query_string}}",
                          "operator": "or",
                          "fuzziness": 0,
                          "boost": 1
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              "from": "{{from_offset}}",
              "size": "{{result_size}}"
            }
          }
      }'
```

I have tried multiple ways to make QuerySourceBuilder by using the above template id and get SearchResponse but I failed,
Any suggestion why it's failing or spring boot doesn't support such a feature?

Answer (score 0):

The next version of Spring Data Elasticsearch (4.3) will have support for searching with search template by using the `NativeSearchQueryBuilder` which then will have a method `withSearchTemplate(SearchTemplateRequestBuilder searchTemplateBuilder)`.

**Edit 02.08.2021:**

Having a deeper look at what is currently available, I noticed that having this on to the `NativeSearchQuery`is wrong. We will need to change this to add a corresponding method to the `ElasticseachOperations` and the implementations.

So in 4.3 there will be a solution, I will update this answer with details as sson as it's implemented.

**Edit 29.10.2021:**

won't be in 4.3, I have no capacity to implement this until release of 4.3, so it will be postponed.

Comment: but sir currently I am using ES version 7.13 will it work with it?

Comment: would you please give me any link or help me with an example for the same?

Comment: Thanks @P.J.Meisch will be waiting for your update on this

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: no, this is still open https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/1891